# How to put List<String[]> in a Map<String, List<String>>

Tags: java, logic

[image]

This is my `List<String[]>` object, that i have to put in a hashmap - `Map<String, List<String>>`.
The first array of Strings, are my keys.
I have to put other arrays in order - First Row = First Key, Second Row = Second key ecc..

I have tried to write by me an algorithm, but don't know how to finish

```
    public Map<String, List<String>> getMapWithListOfStrings() throws IOException {
    Map<String, List<String>> returningMap = new HashMap<>();
    List<String[]> readAll = csvReader.readAll();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        for (String get : readAll.get(i)) {
            returningMap.put(get, new ArrayList<String>());
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < returningMap.size(); i++) {
    }
    return returningMap;
}
```

Comment: If you want to feed the array of strings (String[]) into the Map, create List<String[]> And post your code so we can see what you tried to do.

Comment: map.add("keyString", "listString");

Comment: Hi, What do you mean by the "The first array of Strings, are my keys"? Is the first element of each String array your key or does the first element of `readAll` contain all the keys and the remaining elements are the values?

Comment: Contains the remaining elements with the values. The keys are only in the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you needed?

```java
public Map<String, List<String>> getMapWithListOfStrings() {
    Map<String, List<String>> returningMap = new HashMap<>();
    List<String[]> readAll = csvReader.readAll();
    String[] keys = readAll.get(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        String key = keys[i];
        List<String> value = new ArrayList<>();
        // j = 0 is excluded - it contains the keys, not the values
        for(int j = 1; j < readAll.size(); j++) {
            String iValue = readAll.get(j)[i];
            value.add(iValue);
        }
        returningMap.put(key, value);
    }
    return returningMap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not absolutely sure whether I fully understand your problem, but I guess something like the following (code is untested) should solve your issue.

```
String[] keys = readAll.get(0);

// Make sure there is one key per line of data.
if(keys.length!=readAll.size()-1) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid CSV format!");
}

// Put all the data lines together with their respective key into your Map.
for(int i=1;i<readAll.size();i++) {
    returningMap.put(keys[i-1],Arrays.asList(readAll.get(i)));
}
```